# parse $.post response in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I got `$.post` response as an array. How can I parse this using jQuery?

I need output as

```
array[0][gender]
array[1][lang]
```

Here is the response

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
   (
       [gender] => <label for="genderType">Gender</label><input type="radio" id="femaleId" class="radioBtn" name="genderType" checked="checked" value="1"/>input type="radio" id="maleId" class="radioBtn" name="genderType" value="2" />Male 
       [lang] => <label for="email">Preferred Language:</label><select class='selectStaff dateClass' name='lang' id='lang'><option value=""></option>\n<option value="English">English</option>\n</select>
   )

)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like a `print_r()`. Instead of `print_r()`ing out the results, why not `print json_encode()` them, so it's in a format JavaScript understands natively?

Comment: Thanks for your response  after Json_encode i got response like [{"gender":"<label for=\"genderType\">Gender<\/label><input type=\"radio\" id=\"femaleId\" class=\"radioBtn\" name=\"genderType\" checked=\"checked\" value=\"1\"\/>Female ","lang":"<label for=\"email\">Preferred Language:<\/label><select class='selectStaff dateClass' name='lang' id='lang'><option value=\"\"><\/option>\\n<o<option value=\"Korean\">Korean<\/option>\\n<option value=\"Armenian\">Armenian<\/option>\\n<\/select><\/br>"}]  Can you  help me how can i do it now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function on your returned json.

Example:

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(returnedData);
```

Comment: Better yet, set the `dataType` to json and skip the call to `parseJSON`.